# How to add a space after a diacritical mark if it came at the end of the line

Tags: python

I'm using this regular expression to remove an Arabic diacritical mark from a subtitle file, How it could be modified to add a space after the diacritical mark if the diacritical mark came at the end of line? I'm using python 2.7.

```
file_content = re.sub(u'\u0651', '', file_content)
```

like

اعطني المفكّ

I need to add a space after ّ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` marks an end of line, so you can use:

```
file_content = re.sub(u'\u0651$', u'\u0651 ', file_content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the regular expression is working great.